# processing js sketch not loading

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

This is my markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas data-processing-sources="main.pde" height="500" width="700"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `main.pde` file:

```
// Global variables
float radius = 50.0;
int X, Y;
int nX, nY;
int delay = 16;

// Setup the Processing Canvas
void setup(){
  size( 200, 200 );
  strokeWeight( 10 );
  frameRate( 15 );
  X = width / 2;
  Y = height / 2;
  nX = X;
  nY = Y;  
}

// Main draw loop
void draw() {
  radius = radius + sin( frameCount / 4 );

  // Track circle to new destination
  X+=(nX-X)/delay;
  Y+=(nY-Y)/delay;

  // Fill canvas grey
  background( 100 );

  // Set fill-color to blue
  fill( 0, 121, 184 );

  // Set stroke-color white
  stroke(255); 

  // Draw circle
  ellipse( X, Y, radius, radius );                  
}

// Set circle's next destination
void mouseMoved(){
  nX = mouseX;
  nY = mouseY;  
}
```

When the page loads I get an error in the console that reads:

```
Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: main.pde ==> File is empty.
```

Why is this happening? the file is clearly not empty. I have no clue whats going wrong and have been at this for over an hour. Please help.

Comment: For it is working at wamp server. Starting it without wamp server I get error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present ...` and `Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: main.pde ==> XMLHttpRequest failure,...`. It is strage that you got error with `../main.pde` path.

Comment: @AntoJurkovic I'm guessing you are using chrome. You are getting that error because chrome does not allow local files to be served without using local host. You should look at your IIS configuration.

Comment: My first sentence should be: For your information it is working with wamp server.

Comment: I've spun up a nodejs server to serve the files and I am getting an error there. What is the difference between that and wamp? Both use localhost

Comment: I don't know if there is any difference. As I understand, you have your html file, processing.js and main.pde in the same directory. What happen if you load main.pde instead of html file? Do you get it loaded as text file or you get an error?

Comment: I use Chrome with wamp and it works

Answer (score 0):

From the [processing issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=759):

> The .pde file is empty because Chrome blocks access to it. This happens for all files that it thinks do not come from the same domain and local files are treated the same way. This is a normal security measure.

From the [processing.js quickstart](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html):

> Processing.js will automatically scan the document on page load for  elements with data-processing-sources attributes, download the files using XMLHTTPRequest, and feed them to the Processing-to-JavaScript translator. The resulting JavaScript is run using eval.

So if you use node.js as a html server, it must serve the XMLHTTPRequests.